# jquery dblclick() and keyup() functions not...functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a clone of Instagram with the functionality of "liking" a photo by double-clicking and entering comments into a comment field. I have the 
following functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'https://codesmith-precourse.firebaseio.com/instagram/-JqL35o8u6t3dTQaFXSV.json';
    loadInstagram(url);
    $('.image').on('dblclick', function(){
        $(this).closest("#instagram-wrap").find(".like").append("mickyshaked ");
    });
    $('textarea').on('keyup', function(event) {
        if((event.keyCode || event.which) == 13){
            event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("#instagram-wrap").find(".comments").append('<div class="comment">'+$(this).val()+'</div>');
        $(this).val("Add a comment...");
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT
Here is the get request that retrieves the sample feed:

```
function loadInstagram(url){
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('data.length: ',data.length);
                console.log('data[0]: ', data[0])
                count = data.length;
                var likeCount = {};
                for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    var photoURL = (data[i]);
                    likeCount[photoURL] = 0;
                    console.log(photoURL);
                    $('#instagram').append('<div class="instagram-wrap"><img class="image" src="'+photoURL+'"/><div class="likeWrap"><span class="likesIcon">♥</span><span class="likeNames"></span></div><div class="comments">Comments section</div><textarea class="commentarea" placeholder="Add a comment..."></textarea></div>');
                }
            }
        })
    })
};
```

Here is the html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Instagram Feed</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='feed.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="feedstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
    <div id="header">
        <img id="homeicon" src="homeicon.png"/>
        <span id='logo'>Instagram</span>
        <img id="userimage" src="http://www.thegrindradio.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/instagram-camera-logo-50x50.png"/> 
        <span id="username">mickyshaked</span>
    </div>
    <div class='body'>
        <div id="instagram"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post the HTML structure as well, so it is easier for us to find the bug. By now, the only thing I can think of is the "this" in line 2 of the first code snipped, try removing the quotation marks.

Comment: any console error?

Comment: You've used `.click()` - that binds a *single* click handler. The selector you pass to `.closest()` has a # in one case and not the other, so presumably the second one is wrong. You should not have duplicate element ids in your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because there are a lot of mistakes in it.

1. inside your click handler for the `.image` element, you wrapped the `this` keyword in single-quotes when you shouldn't.
2. inside your keyup handler for the textarea, you forgot to add the `#` for `instagram-wrap` so that it selects the element by its ID.

Anyway, here's how I made that work (jsfiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hmrh5112/)). If we're saying you want a double-click functionality, so use the `dblclick` event instead of `click`.

Also, you are appending a `.comments` element inside another `.comments` element everytime `Enter` is pressed on the textbox. That will result to all the comments being nested on each other. I think you just want the `.comments` element to be the wrapper and each comment be just `.comment`.

PS: I don't know your HTML structure so I just assumed it based on your javascript.

Comment: going to edit to show you what i've got. doesn't seem to effect anything and i'm getting a $ not defined ref error in sublime

Comment: will find() go further down the tree than just the first level of children?

Comment: yup, `.find()` will go further down. the undefined `$` in sublime might just be accurate, as it is defined as a global var by jquery, so just dont worry about that

Comment: @MickyShaked looking at your code, I think you got something wrong. After loading the instagram data, you appended `.instagram-wrap` elements (you're using `instagram-wrap` as classes), but when you call `.closest()` you pass in `#instagrap-wrap` (as an ID). I guess that's why it doesn't seem to work. change your parameter to `closest()` into `.instragram-wrap` and it might work

Comment: good catch, i made that change but it still doesnt seem to work. I have been getting the "$ is not defined" ref error in sublime desipte having the jquery script CDN above the javascript script

Comment: don't worry about the undefined error in sublime, it just means that it couldn't find where the `$` function is being defined within that file (it is actually defined inside the jquery script from the CDN). as long as you dont get that error in your browser console, that's not a problem